# WordPress : If Statement with HTML and Includes

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, include

I want to include a different inline `<style>` tag that contains a php include in my wordpress header.php file based on wether it's my blog or it's a page.

in simple words i want my blog to have this in the `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
        <?php include '../css/1.css.php';?>
</style>
```

and i want my pages to have this other one in the `<head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
        <?php include '../css/2.css.php';?>
</style>
```

I've found this snippet and the distinction between blog and pages works, the problem is the include line

```
<?php
if(is_page()){
    echo 'Foo';
    include ('../css/above-the-fold-contact.css.php');
    echo 'Example: one';
}
else{
    echo 'Foo something else';
    include ('../css/above-the-fold-blog.css.php');
    echo 'Example: two';
}
?>
```

it does inject the right file in the right page, but I need to wrap the include around `<style>` tags, not doing so cause the content of the file to be injected as plain text. how do I do that? what's the syntax? any help is really appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: do u mean echo "<style type='text/css'>"

Comment: i don't know @user1844933 sorry :D i'm really bad at php I'm not sure what echo does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo '<style type="text/css">';

    if( is_page() )  { include '../css/above-the-fold-contact.css.php'; }
    else             { include '../css/above-the-fold-blog.css.php'; }

    echo '</style>';
```

**EDIT** :  Just a quick mention - if your CSS is not generated dynamically, then there are better ways of doing this ( like `wp_enqueue_style`, for example )